# Restricting @Input to list of predefined values in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to restrict the `@Input` to list of predefined values but still, any values are accepted from the parent. Even with `Enum` also it accepting everything and just not the enum values.

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-button',
    template: `<div>
                <button [type]="buttonType">
                    {{buttonText}}
                </button>
            </div>`
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() buttonType: 'reset' | 'submit' | 'button' = 'button'; 
    @Input() buttonText: string;

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-button buttonText="Action1" buttonType="accepts anything"></app-button>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Test Component';

   ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: You are now using it as a standard HTML attribute. Maybe adding brackets `[buttonType]` would help? It also depends on how strict your IDE is and if you are using the normal build or the aot production build which is a lot more strict.

Comment: Why use `[buttonType]` if I don't want to bind?

Comment: You could use a user defined type guard https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict this with help of **[`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)** which is actually monitor **[`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)** in every change.

Do some changes like below,

```
 buttonTypesList: any = ['reset', 'submit', 'button'];

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes['buttonType']) {
      this.buttonType  = this.buttonTypesList.includes(this.buttonType) ? this.buttonType : 'button';
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve your goal for now, even if you change the `buttonType` type to integer from string it will still accept the string value without any hesitation.
I think this is partly because the binding is Angular's own feature, not of Typescript, so Typescript can't recognize that you are passing some other type.